# How to move specific files from a folder to another folder specified by a txt file?

Tags: batch-file

I have lots of xml files which I want to move them to some folders. I want to specify the list of files which to move in a txt file.

Let me explain more...

It's a mini-dictionary with over 5000 words and I want to seperate them into 20 units. Because of that I want to move not copy the xml files to see which words remains and decide for them to be in which unit.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Is the source folder for all files the same, or does the full origin path need to be specified?  Is the destination folder for all files the same, or does it need specified for each file separately?

Comment: source folder for all files is the same and I can move each part of xml files one by one. I mean for example move the first 100 files then the second 100 files and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will move the files listed in `file.txt` and move them to the folder shown on line 2.

```
@echo off
set "target=d:\folder"
md "%target%" 2>nul
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do move "%%a" "%target%"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy files, you must put this code into a batch file

```
@echo off
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit1
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit2
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit3
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit4
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit5
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit6
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit7
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit8
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit9
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit10
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit11
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit12
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit13
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit14
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit15
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit16
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit17
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit18
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit19
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit20
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit21
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit22
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit23
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit24
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit25
mkdir "C:\newfolder\unit26
echo each unit has diffrent words. EX: Unit 1 has a's, Unit 2 has b's, etc.
pause >nul
cls
set /p u1=do you want to move unit 1?y/n?
if %u1%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\a*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit1"
)
set /p u2=do you want to move unit 2?y/n?
if %u2%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\b*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit2"
)
set /p u3=do you want to move unit 3?y/n?
if %u3%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\c*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit3"
)
set /p u4=do you want to move unit 4?y/n?
if %u4%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\d*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit4"
)
set /p u5=do you want to move unit 5?y/n?
if %u5%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\e*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit5"
)
set /p u6=do you want to move unit 6?y/n?
if %u6%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\f*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit6"
)
set /p u7=do you want to move unit 7?y/n?
if %u7%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\g*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit7"
)
set /p u8=do you want to move unit 8?y/n?
if %u8%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\h*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit8"
)
set /p u9=do you want to move unit 9?y/n?
if %u9%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\i*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit9"
)
set /p u10=do you want to move unit 10?y/n?
if %u10%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\j*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit10"
)
set /p u11=do you want to move unit 11?y/n?
if %u11%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\k*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit11"
)
set /p u12=do you want to move unit 12?y/n?
if %u12%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\l*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit12"
)
set /p u13=do you want to move unit 13?y/n?
if %u13%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\m*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit13"
)
set /p u14=do you want to move unit 14?y/n?
if %u14%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\n*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit14"
)
set /p u15=do you want to move unit 15?y/n?
if %u15%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\o*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit15"
)
set /p u16=do you want to move unit 16?y/n?
if %u16%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\p*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit16"
)
set /p u17=do you want to move unit 17?y/n?
if %u17%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\q*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit17"
)
set /p u18=do you want to move unit 18?y/n?
if %u18%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\r*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit18"
)
set /p u19=do you want to move unit 19?y/n?
if %u19%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\s*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit19"
)
set /p u20=do you want to move unit 20?y/n?
if %u20%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\t*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit20"
)
set /p u21=do you want to move unit 21?y/n?
if %u21%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\u*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit21"
)
set /p u22=do you want to move unit 22?y/n?
if %u22%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\v*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit22"
)
set /p u23=do you want to move unit 23?y/n?
if %u23%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\w*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit23"
)
set /p u24=do you want to move unit 24?y/n?
if %u24%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\x*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit24"
)
set /p u25=do you want to move unit 25?y/n?
if %u25%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\y*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit25"
)
set /p u26=do you want to move unit 26?y/n?
if %u26%==y(
move /-y "C:\folder\z*.xml "C:\newfolder\unit26"
)
echo DONE!
pause >nul
```

This new Method will move each letter into a unit of its own.

EDIT: AND IT IS NOW USER DEFINED!

i hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the time spending my question but another user had answered me and it was exactly what I want can you look at the other answer?

Comment: wow. i spend over 3 days figuring this out and @foxidrive did it in less than a day... seems like patience is not a virtue. and i did it all for nothing.. :(